# Plotting two lists with different lengths with interpolation

Tags: python, matplotlib

I need to plot two lists of numbers against each other, but I need to extend the range of both.

The first list contains the number of time a thing happens (which I'm simulating). The second contains the cumulative frequency. An example of both is:

```
number_of_times = [77, 78, 79, 80, 81, 82, 83, 84, 85, 86, 87, 88, 90]
cumsum = [0.01, 0.02, 0.03, 0.04, 0.09, 0.16, 0.3, 0.46, 0.74, 0.89, 0.95, 0.99, 1.0]
```

How can I plot these against each other, with the x-axis (numvber_of_times) having a range of 0-100, but making sure that the cumulative frequency still matches up?

Currently I'm using

```
plt.plot(num.keys(), cumsum)
plt.show()
```

but this just doesn't look that good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are currently trying to plot the keys of a dictionary `num` against the list `cumsum`. Simply feed the `plot` method the two lists as arguments, and set the x-limits with `xlim`.

```
number_of_times = [77, 78, 79, 80, 81, 82, 83, 84, 85, 86, 87, 88, 90]
cumsum = [0.01, 0.02, 0.03, 0.04, 0.09, 0.16, 0.3, 0.46, 0.74, 0.89, 0.95, 0.99, 1.0]

plt.plot(number_of_times, cumsum)
plt.xlim(0, 100)

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! I didn't know you could just set the limits!